# Does data used by an app get deleted when a user installs an update?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is data in isolated storage remain after user installs an update to your app in windows phone 7?

Also are IsolatedStorageSettings preserved after an update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, IsolatedStorage is only wiped if the user uninstalls the app. Upgrading it leaves previous data intact. Obviously, if the new version of your app wants the data to be in a different format, you'll have to handle the conversion yourself in code.

Note that as a developer, choosing Rebuild All, or Clean Build -> Build in Visual Studio causes the sideloaded app to be uninstalled and reinstalled from your device (and emulator) the next time it is deployed. This will result in IsolatedStorage being wiped. However, an incremental build does not affect IsolatedStorage.

Comment: +1 for the "Rebuild All". This feature would have saved me a lot of headaches. Thanks for the answer.