# What happens to Isolated Storage stored objects during an update

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

If I store some serialized objects in isolated storage and then two months down the line create an update for my app. Does the isolated storage get removed during the update procedure?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557809/does-data-used-by-an-app-get-deleted-when-a-user-installs-an-update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data stored in isolated storage remains exactly as it was after you update as long as the update is done via the Marketplace. If the app is "sideloaded" or deployed by Visual Studio/Expression Blend then it will uninstall/reinstall not upgrade so you'll loose what's in isolated storage. If you don't do a Rebuild All in Visual Studio, then it will leave isolated storage alone and effectively perform an upgrade.